# golang(cgo) --- not determine kind of name for C.quit

Tags: go, cgo

There is not any `errors`,but the "not determine kind of name for C.quit"

I linked the shared library with #cgo LDFLAGS  in my project. What are the possible reasons?

Answer (score -2):

**I used the function 'quit' (A careless mistake), but there isnot the function in C code.**